# How to get my last google map location?

Tags: java, jsp, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

Google maps have this button which shows your location based on your last track. Actually if i click this button it says that it got my location from my phone and it shows the correct address. Right now my application can track the user's location, but with a major downside. If the device has no GPS it tracks the IP location which the most of the time is not the actual user's position. Is there any way that i can integrate this feature in my application? I'm searching for an API but i haven't found something yet. Thanks

[image: http://puu.sh/lq4n0/e53483c429.png]

Answer (score 1):

By following I assume you are talking about **WEB**-application.

Your browser can detect your location if you allow that. This data (latitude and longitude) could be obtained via JavaScript. 
For instance: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp 
or  https://github.com/onury/geolocator. 
Hundreds of example can be googled using query "javascrip geolocation library".

Comment: You misunderstood me, my application use already html5 geolocation. But it's not accurate when devices like Desktop PC's don't have GPS. Although google saves recent locations from other devices like phones which the location is more accurate. I'm trying to get this user location "history". Thanks